# gcloud functions call throwing invalid JSON error

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm following [this](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-using-gcloud-tool-ccf3127fdf1a) tutorial on how to set up a local gcloud functions environment. I have this script set up and deployed:

```
exports.helloGET = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    
    // Example input: {“name”: “Junior”}
    if (req.body.name === undefined) { 
      // This is an error case, as “name” is required.
      res.status(400).send('No name defined!');
    } else {
      console.log(req.body.name);
      res.status(200).send('Hello ' + req.body.name);
    }
};
```

I tried testing this function on the Cloud GUI (the website) and it works when you test it with `{"name": "Junior"}`. It returns `Hello Junior` as expected.

I now want to be able to run the test locally from the command line, so referring to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call), they give the example:

`gcloud functions call helloWorld --data='{"message": "Hello World!"}'`

However, when I try to run the following:

`gcloud functions call helloGET --data='{"name": "Junior"}' --region=northamerica-northeast1`

I keep getting

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) Invalid value for [--data]: Is not a valid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Why is this happening? I'm doing exactly what the docs & the tutorial are doing.

Comment: It should not, but does it make any difference if you drop the equals sign after the flag? `--data '...'`

Comment: If that doesn't work, what happens if you escape the quotes? `--data="{\"name\": \"value\"}"`

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: In the second link you shared is mentioned that: depending on your environment you might need to escape characters in --data flag value differently. Did any of the above suggestions in comments work? Another option would be: `--data '{\"name\":\"value\"}' ` or  `--data={\"name\":\"value\"`

Comment: @DazWilkin `--data '...'` didn't work, but `--data="{\"name\": \"value\"}"` did! Do you have a clue of why this is happening? I've never had problems with quotes on my terminal before. Note: I'm on Windows

Comment: I think it's worth reporting this behavior on Google's [Issue Tracker for Cloud SDK](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102). If the behavior is necessarily inconsistent between Windows and other platforms then Google ought to at least document the Windows case alongside others. I appreciate that you're using a 3rd-party's tutorial but, Google's own documentation for [`gcloud functions call`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/call) uses the same example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to repro your issue (on Linux).

I wonder whether you're:

- using a non-Linux OS and this an incompatibility
- inadvertently including non-standard `'` or `"`

Deployed:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy hello \
--entry-point=hello \
--runtime=nodejs12 \
--trigger-http \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then:

```sh
gcloud functions call hello \
--data='{"name":"Freddie"}' \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
executionId: 7igxh5sfvjvk
result: Hello Freddie
```

And:

```sh
gcloud functions call hello \
--data='{"name":"Freddie"}' \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--log-http
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../functions/hello:call?alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
b'Authorization': --- Token Redacted ---
b'accept': b'application/json'
b'accept-encoding': b'gzip, deflate'
b'content-length': b'34'
b'content-type': b'application/json'
== headers end ==
== body start ==
{"data": "{\"name\":\"Freddie\"}"}
== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
status: 200
-- headers start --
...
-- body start --
{
  "executionId": "7igx3sfj3ate",
  "result": "Hello Freddie"
}

-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 0.289 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
executionId: 7igx3sfj3ate
result: Hello Freddie
```

> **NOTE** curl encodes the value of data as `"{\"name\":\"Freddie\"}`

And:

```sh
ENDPOINT=$(\
  gcloud functions describe hello \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")

TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

curl \
--request POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
--data '{"name":"Freddie"}' \
${ENDPOINT}
Hello Freddie
```